# Can i run an .out file inside ios? Is there any external library or some method?

Tags: ios, c, swift, xcode, bridge

I need to run a .out file through swift or c, as I have created a bridge to run C code in swift. I would like to know if I can use some method to run an .out file

I have tried the command system or nftw but these are not helpful

Comment: Welcome to SO. "Doesn't work" is not a useful error description. Please edit your question to include your current attempt (see [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) together with a detailled error description. What does not work? Do get an error result? Which?

Comment: `a.out` is the default name of a binary executable built by a Unix-style compiler.  Binary executables are, in fact, executable.  Do understand, however, that the ".out" part does not designate a broader file type in this context, and that on Unix-like systems, including Mac, a file's name is not a factor in whether it is executable.

Comment: There are some utility programs in AppStore like a-Shell that can run programs.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.